# Invalid date format in datatype column in BODS job to Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, etl, sap-data-services

I am using SAP BODS and I am trying to fetch data from an ORACLE server using SQL query transformation. Now The table has a column named `latest_changed_date` which is a datetime column. I only want yesterday and current day data from that table. Now since the column is datetime, I need to convert it to date, but when I am using `to_date` function I get the following error.

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC.TEST
WHERE TO_DATE(LATEST_CHANGED_DATE) = TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1)
```

The database error message is

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

I tried giving date format in TO_DATE condition as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC.TEST
WHERE TO_DATE(LATEST_CHANGED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Here I got the error:

> date format picture ends before converting entire input string

I used `trunc` function also and again got either:

```
not a valid month
```

or

```
inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

Below is a sample data for the column. I just need data for current and day before data from the column.

[image]

Update: I think the main issue is that I am not able to determine the proper datatype for the column in the source table and currently I don't have an option to determine that.

Comment: Why are you using `to_date()` if the column is already a date/time?

Comment: Because I datetime will also have time value. I need data from yesterday 12AM. So I thought of using to_date which will only give me date part

Comment: `DATETIME` is not a valid Oracle data type. What is the actual data type of the column? Is it `DATE` (which includes a time component in Oracle) or `TIMESTAMP` (which has fractional seconds)?

Comment: This I cannot determine because I am using SAP BODS to connect to an external oracle server of some different team of my organization.Only option I have is to check all probable ways to fetch the data

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: Maybe LATEST_CHANGED_DATE has VARCHAR2 type? Please check what is a type of this column.

Comment: Is it the `WHERE` condition that is generating the error or is SAP trying to do some data type conversions on the results and the error is being generated by the `SELECT *` portion of the query? What happens if you do `SELECT 'X' FROM ABC.TEST WHERE LATEST_CHANGED_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE-1 )`?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to implicitly cast your dates to strings and convert them back using `TO_DATE( string_value, format_model )` you can use `TRUNC()` to truncate `SYSDATE` to the start of the day:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ABC.TEST
WHERE  LATEST_CHANGED_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE-1 )
```

Comment: Had tried this too, got-  inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: @VandanBhardwaj This is the correct answer if latest_changed_date is `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. If it’s something else it would really help to know what it is. Can you query this database at all, e.g. can you `select dump(latest_changed_date) from abc.test where rownum = 1`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I cannot query the database but what I did was replicate the entire table to one of my oracle DB and query it. The result was following. TYP=12 LEN=7: 120,106,12,26,19,26,52

Comment: @VandanBhardwaj type 12 is an Oracle `DATE` (includes time) so @MTO’s answer should work. If you now have a test copy you can access, perhaps you can narrow down the test case.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The frustrating thing is, all of the suggestions here is working fine on my test data but as soon as I connect and replicate conditional data, the suggestions fail.

Comment: @VandanBhardwaj Start with `SELECT * FROM ABC.TEST` and see if that works then try adding `WHERE LATEST_CHANGED_DATE = DATE '2018-12-05'` then `WHERE LATEST_CHANGED_DATE = SYSDATE` then  `WHERE LATEST_CHANGED_DATE = SYSDATE - 1` and slowly build up your query until you find the exact part where the error is.

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC.TEST
where sysdate-LATEST_CHANGED_DATE<=sysdate-(sysdate-2);
```

for example take this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ' DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT * FROM d061_dates ;

 03-DEC-2018 17:44:38
 25-AUG-2018 17:44:42
 30-AUG-2018 17:44:46
 01-DEC-2018 17:44:49
 02-DEC-2018 17:46:31

SELECT * FROM d061_dates
where sysdate-a<=sysdate-(sysdate-2);

 03-DEC-2018 17:44:38
 02-DEC-2018 17:46:31
```

you have to take sysdate minus on both sides to get comparision by a number which is less than equal to 2 to get day and day before yesterday and its giving the correct output.

thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This does not ignore the time component.

Comment: Why do you need `sysdate` on both parts of the equation?

Comment: @NicoHaase its because there should be a difference between the dates we cant add date in oracle to get day and day before yesterday as mentioned by the user   and it is also giving right results.

Comment: By pure logic, the result should be the same if `sysdate` is removed on both sides

Comment: @MT0 by default date is stored as datetime yoou jsut neeed to change the session for nls_date_format what are you talking about this does not ignore the time component??

Comment: @NicoHaase no that wont be a number anymore thats why we have to take difference by sysdate

Comment: I'm afraid you don't quite understand date arithmetic, @nikhil.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Getting inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER error

Comment: @VandanBhardwaj  its working in my system whats wrong what is the datatype of your LAST_DATE_CHANGED??

Comment: `any_value - (any_value - 2) = any_value - any_value + 2 = 2`. You do not need to use `SYSDATE - ( SYSDATE - 2)` as the `SYSDATE` cancels out and you just get `2`. Also, this answer is incorrect as the OP said "I only want yesterday and current day data from that table" and this will get dates that are greater than 2 days before the current instant and could return values from 2 days before today.

Comment: @VandanBhardwaj what is the datatype of LAST_DATE_CHANGED ??

Comment: As I have said in the original post, I am connecting to an external DB and as it is I cannot directly query on it to check the datatype. The one option I have is to use a SQL Query transform in my ETL tool and I can directly query on it.